How to Implement a Seek Feature in flutter_tts Plugin
I'm working on a Flutter project using the flutter_tts plugin to handle text-to-speech functionality. I've encountered a challenge while trying to implement a seek feature (i.e., allowing users to skip to a specific time or part of the speech).
Since the flutter_tts API doesn't seem to natively support seeking, I'm wondering if anyone has found a workaround or alternative approach to achieve this functionality. Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
void setUpTTS() {
startTimeout();
_setAwaitOptions();
flutterTts.setProgressHandler((text, start, end, word) {
  currentWord = start;
  wordEnd = end;
  notifyListeners();
});
flutterTts.getVoices.then((results) {
  try {
    List<Map> allVoices = List<Map>.from(results);
    voices = allVoices.map((voice) => VoicesModel.fromMap(voice)).toList();
    loadPreferences();
    englishVoices = _filterVoicesByLanguage(voices, "en");
    notifyListeners();
    _setUpHandlers();
  } catch (e) {
    print('An error occurred while setting up TTS: $e');
  }
}).catchError((error) {
  print('An error occurred while fetching voices: $error');
});}


  Future<void> speak(String text) async {
// Stop any ongoing TTS before starting a new one
if (ttsState == TtsState.playing) {
  await stop();
}
await flutterTts.setVolume(volume);
await flutterTts.setSpeechRate(speed);
await flutterTts.setPitch(pitch);
if (text.isNotEmpty) {
  await flutterTts.speak(text);
} }



Future<void> seekForward(String word) async {
    if (ttsState == TtsState.playing || ttsState == TtsState.paused) {
      await flutterTts.pause(); 

      // Define the seek time in milliseconds, adjust based on speech speed
      int seekTime = (15000 * speed).toInt();
      int newStart = (currentWord ?? 0) + seekTime;

      if (newStart >= wordEnd!) {
        newStart = wordEnd! - 1;
      }

      await flutterTts.speak(getTextFromPosition(newStart, word));
      currentWord = newStart;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

